Ola Hallengren: not accepting two databases in IndexOptimize scripts
In Ola's documentation there is this procedure:

USER_DATABASES, -Db1  All user databases, except Db1 If you want make
in all database except in DB1.

But the second parameter is marked with red underscore when I put
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

DECLARE @GUID uniqueidentifier = '3CF5B469-47AD-4F25-80DD-80E73946A730';

EXECUTE ola.dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = USER_DATABASES,-akBase,


Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near 'akBase'.
Completion time: 2024-08-16T06:59:31.4956051-06:00

What did I do wrong?

Your command is missing the quotes:
EXECUTE ola.dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES,-akBase',

Check the Examples section of the documentation to see that and other details that might help you better understand.

oo dear lord, thanks Ronaldo.
incredible because the procedure in the ola site doesn't mention exactly what you post in here.

@MarcoAntonio, the need to enclose string parameter values in single quotes is standard T-SQL syntax, nothing specific to Ola's scripts. The EXECUTE documentation specifies: If the value of a parameter is an object name, character string, or qualified by a database name or schema name, the whole name must be enclosed in single quotation marks.

@MarcoAntonio glad I could help. Please, remember to mark as the correct answer if it solved your problem ;)
